Is any presheaf a product of skyscraper sheaves?
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{F} \in \mathsf{PSh}(X)$. For each $x \in X$, let $\mathscr{F}_x$ denote the stalk of $\mathscr{F}$ at $x$. For each $x \in X$, let $\mathscr{G}^x$ be the skyscraper sheaf of $\mathscr{F}_x$ at $x$, i.e.
$$
\mathscr{G}^x(U) = \begin{cases} \mathscr{F}_x & x \in U \\ \{*\} & x \not\in U \\ \end{cases}
$$
with the obvious restriction maps. Now take $\mathscr{G} = \prod_{x \in X} \mathscr{G}^x$, i.e.
$$
\mathscr{G}(U) = \prod_{x \in U} \mathcal{F}_x
$$
Now for any open subset $U$ and point $x \in U$, we have a map
$$
\mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}_x
$$
This induces a map
$$
\mathcal{F}(U) \to \prod_{x \in U} \mathcal{F}_x = \mathcal{G}(U)
$$
hence we obtain a map
$$
\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}
$$
Is this map always an isomorphism? If not, are there any natural conditions under which this is true?

No, this map is typically not an isomorphism and you should not expect it to be. For example, $\mathcal{G}$ is always a sheaf and it is furthermore flasque, meaning any inclusion $U\subseteq V$ of open sets in $X$ induces a surjective restriction map $\mathcal{G}(V)\rightarrow\mathcal{G}(U)$. Thus, $\mathcal{F}$ being a flasque sheaf is a necessary condition for this map to be an isomorphism, but even that is not sufficient and I cannot think of any sufficient condition besides the tautological "if $\mathcal{F}$ is a product of skyscraper sheaves". In case $X$ is discrete, this is always the case, but otherwise you would typically not expect it to be, at least intuitively speaking.
That said, the sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ is very much important and useful. It is part of the Godement resolution that can be used to construct sheaf cohomology.
